# White noise generator with more incident low frequencies

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design

I'm trying to make a White Noise Generator.

I'm implementing the schematic below. The Q1 generates white noise (as you can see, the collector pin is not connected), and the signal is amplified by the second transistor. As you can see from the collected data from the oscilloscope, and evident by the FFT in violet, low frequencies are more prominent - which should not happen in a white noise response.

I wonder if this is happening because of some antenna phenomena in the circuit (that I could tackle by using a faraday cage), or maybe the capacitors are creating this effect (and I may do a high-pass filter to cutoff frequencies below ~25kHz, from where the signal seems to be more uniform).

Why do you think this problem arises and what do you suggest me to do in order to correct it and improve the white noise signal?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably coming from the 1/f noise of the transistor

Comment: @ErnestoG could you elaborate on that? And am I supposed to just cut it off with a high-pass filter or is there a better way?

Comment: @ludicrous, look up i/f noise. Hint: which has more energy: high or low frequencies? IR or UV photon? Same is true for sound and RF.